# If $f$ is a polynomial s.t. $a\lt b\lt c$, $f(a)\gt f(b)$, and $f(b)\lt f(c)$, then on $[a,c]$ there's a local min. point $m$ s.t. $f(m)\leq f(b)$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, solution-verification

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n \geq 2$. Suppose for three points $a \lt b \lt c$ we know the following: $f(a) \gt f(b)$ and $f(b) \lt f(c)$. Prove that on the interval $[a,c]$ there is a local minimum point $m$ such that $f(m) \leq f(b)$.

I'd like to know if there is a different way of going about this proof. I think my approach (which uses contradiction) is correct, but any additional input or alternative methods are appreciated.

---

Relevant lemma used throughout:

> If $f$ is a $n \geq 2$ degree polynomial, then between any two consecutive $r_1, r_2$ where $f'(r_1)=f'(r_2)=0$, $f$ is strictly decreasing or strictly increasing. Further, if $r_L$ is the most left point where $f'$ evaluates to $0$ and $r_R$ is the most right point where $f'$ evaluates to $0$, then $f$ is strictly increasing or decreasing on $(-\infty,r_L]$ and $[r_R,\infty)$. Note that this implies if $x$ is any arbitrary point where $f'(x) \neq 0$, then there is a neighborhood around $x$ where $f$ is strictly decreasing or increasing.

---

Suppose by contradiction that there does **not** exist a local minimum point $m \in [a,c]$ where $f(m) \leq f(b)$. This negation amounts to: *$m$ is not a minimum point or $f(m)\gt f(b)$*. Clearly, this means that $f(b)$ is not a local minimum point (note that the other option, $f(b) \gt f(b)$, leads to a contradiction). This means that for any $\delta \gt 0$, there is an $x \in (b-\delta,b+\delta)$ such that $f(x) \lt f(b)$.

Applying our lemma, if for any $\delta \gt 0$, there is an $x \in (b-\delta,b+\delta)$ such that $f(x) \lt f(b)$, there are three possibilities (note that $f'(b)$ may, or may not, equal $0$):

1. There is an interval $(b-\delta,b+\delta)$ where $f$ is strictly decreasing
2. There is an interval $(b-\delta,b+\delta)$ where $f$ is strictly increasing
3. There is an interval $(b-\delta_L,b]$ where $f$ is strictly increasing and an interval $[b, b+\delta_R)$ where $f$ is strictly decreasing

**Across all $3$ cases**, we see that there are either left-of-$b$ intervals where $f$ is strictly increasing or right-of-$b$ intervals where $f$ is strictly decreasing. Without loss of generality, consider the case where $f$ is strictly decreasing in a right-of-$b$ interval.

Because $f'$ is *also* a polynomial, we know that there are a finite number of $a_1, a_2, ... a_k \in [b,c]$ such that $f'(a_i)=0$ for any $i \in [1,k]$. Let $a_1$ represent the closest point to $b$, $a_2$ the second closest point to $b$, etc.

Consider the point $a_1$ and the interval $[b,a_1]$. By our lemma, $f$ must be strictly decreasing on this interval, which means $f(a_1) \lt f(b)$. Thus, $a_1$ is either an inflection point or a maximum point (by assumption, it cannot be a minimum point). However, $a_1$ is clearly not a maximum point because the interval to its left is strictly decreasing. Therefore, $a_1$ must be an inflection point. This means that $f$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $[a_1,a_2]$. This argument is repeated until we can finally claim $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[a_{k-1},a_{k}]$.

Further, regardless of whether or not $f'(c)=0$, because $a_k$ must be an inflection point and $a_k$ is the final root of $f'$ along the interval $[b,c]$, it must be the case that $f$ is strictly decreasing along $[a_k,c]$. Therefore, $f$ is strictly decreasing along the interval $[b,c]$. **But** $f(c) \gt f(b)$: a contradiction. $\quad \square$

Comment: I imagine that you want to avoid using general calculus theorems. Right?

Comment: Are you thinking far too complicated? A continuous function has a maximum and a minimum on every compact interval.

Comment: @MartinR so the argument would basically amount to using your referenced theorem to say there is an $m \in [a,c]$ that is less than or equal to any other $x$ in that interval (including $f(b)$). ...And then I would show that, because $f$ is a polynomial, the interval to the left of $m$ must have $f$ strictly decreasing  and the interval to the right of $m$ must have $f$ strictly increasing (which means that $m$ is our desired local min). Correct?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I actually *forgot* the theorem that Martin mentioned hah (or, at least, it was not on my mind when I wrote this). I think the proof is straightforward given that theorem. Cheers~

Comment: @S.Cramer: There is an $m \in [a, b]$ with $f(m) \le f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$, because $f$ is continuous. That $m$ is a minimum, there is no need for further reasoning. – If you want to show that it is a *strict* minimum then you can use the argument from your recent question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4300903/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the input. Final question: you say that my above comment is wrong as written. I assume you are referring to this comment: "...because $f$ is a polynomial, the interval to the left of $m$ must have $f$ strictly decreasing and the interval to the right of $m$ must have $f$ strictly increasing (which means that m is our desired local min)". Could you clarify why this statement is wrong? Should I have more precisely written: "there is a left-neighborhood $[m-\delta,m]$ where $f$ strictly decreases and there is a right-neighborhood $[m,m+\delta]$ where $f$ strictly increases

Comment: @S.Cramer: Yes.